# Is there a way to generate possible short forms?

Tags: python

Consider the string `Building Centre`.  If asked to abbreviate this to fit a specific number of characters, you and I may choose very different but equally valid representations.  For instance, three valid 7 character representations are:

`BLD CNT`

`BLD CTR`

`BLDNGCT`

These are generated by:

1. Using only existing letters in the string (can't abbreviate using z)
2. Using them in the order they appear (`LBD` is not valid since L does not come before B in `Building`).
3. Selecting up to as many characters (including spaces) as indicated.

I'm looking to write a breadth or depth of search based algorithm to generate all such short forms for a given string and desired length.

Before I go about writing the script, I am wondering if something similar has already been implemented.  If not, how would you suggest I write something like this?  Besides `itertools`, are there any useful libraries?

Comment: It doesn't sound like BFS/DFS problem, to me it sounds more like "find all the (ordered) subsequences of certain length" of a string

Comment: `for x in itertools.combinations("Building Centre", 7):
 print "".join(x)`

Comment: "*Besides `itertools` ...*" - Why do you omit `itertools` from the set of possible answers?

Comment: Would `' Centre'` be one of the "equally valid representations"? It seems like if you want plausible abbreviations then you need to add more constraints.

Comment: If this isn't homework but instead you really want to automatically generate plausible abbreviations, this looks promising: https://github.com/ppannuto/python-abbreviate

Comment: @Robᵩ I excluded itertools because I know I could write it in itertools.  I was wondering if there was an easier way or an existing implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be beautifully done with `itertools`:

```
import itertools

text = 'Building Centre'
length = 7
shorts = [''.join(short) for short in itertools.combinations(text, length)]
print(shorts)  # 6435 different versions!
```

Note that `itertools.combinations` does indeed preserve the order. You way want to check out [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

#### Edit

If short forms with fewer than `length` characters should be allowed as well, you can use

```
shorts = list(itertools.chain(*((''.join(short) for short in itertools.combinations(text, l))
                                for l in range(1, length + 1))))
```

As stated in the comments, some short forms get generated twice. To fix this, use e.g. `shorts = list(set(shorts))`.

Comment: "Selecting *up to* as many characters ..." -- so shouldn't you loop over `range(1+length)`?

Comment: Also -- `BDE` (for example) might be *generated* twice but probably shouldn't be *returned* twice. Perhaps run `shorts` through `set()` first.

Comment: AH! See, I was using permutation instead of combination.  Thank you!